# How to get Express App running in Electron

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, electron

used now several hours in google and forums and still couldn't find the correct way to get my electron app running.

## Current setup

I have an express app which sends a request to OpenAI API and sends the answer back to the client.

For this I have created following files:

- app.js (Express app, calling the OpenAI API)
- public/index.html (Starting page which gets delivered from the express server)
- public/index.js (JavaScript code for sending the client request to my express server which then makes the API Call and sends the json result back.

It works as a pure web solution, both on my local machine and on a heroku webserver as well.
Putting everything into electron in works in the dev environment as well.

## Issue

But as soon as I pack/deploy it and run it in Windows with following steps:

```
npx electron-forge import
npm run make
```

Both run sucessfully with no error. Now when I run the win distrubatable:

1. Index.html is displayed correctly
2. Clicking on the button to start for my call in index.js for the express server, nothing happens. I don't get any reaction.

## My code examples

*app.js*

```
const express = require('express')
const {generateMeta} = require("./controllers/openaiController")
const path = require('path')

// app setup
const app = express()
let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 3000;
}
app.listen(port);

// middleware
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// routes
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
})
app.post('/openai/meta', generateMeta)
```

*public/index.js*

```
const response = await fetch('/openai/meta', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({title: textareaContent})
    })
    const data = await response.json()
```

*main.js (electron)*

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
require("./app.js")

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1400,
      height: 900,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
      },
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
    });
    mainWindow.maximize()
   
    mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000/");
    mainWindow.on("closed", function () {
      mainWindow = null;
    });
  }
   
  app.on("ready", createWindow);
   
  app.on("resize", function (e, x, y) {
    mainWindow.setSize(x, y);
  });
   
  app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
      app.quit();
    }
  });
   
  app.on("activate", function () {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "ai_xx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "xxxx",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "test": "test",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "author": "Can XXX",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.17.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "openai": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^6.3.0",
    "electron": "^25.5.0"
  }
}
```

## What I tried so far:

I tried to change the directory information by adding the __dirname to the
app.post('/openai/meta', generateMeta) as well as this is giving me the open ai api call and response.

But didn't work.

I made several changes to the package.json with no success either.

I am very puzzled how electron prod works as everything works in electron dev as intended.

Hope sb can give me a hint what I do wrong.

Thanks a lot in advance, help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check firewalls, antivirus